# Code Repetition Confusion

Tags: android, design-patterns

In my Android Application, I have two activities.

- One Activity lets the user take a picture. This picture is saved, and then uploaded to the server. The server returns some info and displays it in a list.
- The other Activity is a gallery. The user can select a picture, upload it and get the same info in a list (the same as the first activity)

The way I've implemented is this:

- upload and Info task is a seperate AsyncTask called `WebServiceTask`. Both Activities execute this task.
- I created a `WebServiceTaskInvoker` interface so that each activity could specify what happens on preExecute, postExecute, progressUpdate.

The problem is that the two activities pretty much do the exact same thing on preExecute, postExecute and progressUpdate so there's code repetition between the two activities.

- OnPreExecute: Both Activities check internet connectivity
- OnProgressUpdate: Both Activities change a TextView's text
- OnPostExecute: Both Activities create a dynamic ListView and populate
  it with results.

How can I fix this?

- I know one way would be to combine the two activities into one but form past experience, I've known this to be troublesome and messy.
- I could put the UI code in the `WebServiceTask` but that would lead to tight cohesion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement a base class for the two activities that executes common code. Implement the activities as subclasses of your base class to execute different code.

Comment: I had a bit of confusion with that. In android, the view is specified in xml files and instantiated in the activity. The two activities have two different xml so they need to be instantiated differently. In my case, the repeating code is related to updating the ui so I would have to instantiate the UI in the superclass but since the XMLs are different, the instantiation code is different so I can't really put the common code in a super class. I hope I'm being clear

Comment: You can load the view in the subclasses. The UI elements that you are editing can be uninitialized members of the superclass and assigned when you do your OnCreate()/onResume() or wherever you are loading the view.

Comment: It gets called in both of the activities in the `onPreExecute()`, `onProgressUpdate()` and `onPostExecuteMethods()` methods;

Comment: You could create a method in the superclass that executes the common code and then call it from those methods in the subclass... too much of that and it can certainly start to feel hacky though.

Comment: Yup, that's what I did. It does look a bit weird though but it makes more sense than the repetition I had going on before :)

Comment: The superclass implements the interface so it handles what is in common between the activities. The subclasses implement code relevant  to the activity. There's hardly any overlap so in the end, I guess it is a clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate to Catherine's suggestion is to create an activity mode enumeration.

Pass this mode as an extra when launching your activity.

If the mode is MODE_GALLERY then load the gallery.xml layout and populate it, if not then load the other layout.

Just make sure that you use the same id's for the common views, an easy way to do this is to use the include tag in your layout files.

The advantage of this is that you only have one activity file instead of three which would be required for the subclassing method.

You may also be able use fragments, but I don't have any experience with these so I can't advise ou further.

One last note, I would avoid putting UI code into a task.

Comment: I've tried combining Activities before and it's a real pain in the butt: The code is difficult to follow, difficult to maintain. I really would like to avoid that.